# Ruby on Rails : Query using array results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm sure this is blatantly simple to many of you, but as a noob I am having an issue wrapping my brain around it.

I have a model called Season where the data looks like this - (all of the field names are all lower case, shown below with caps for readability)

```
Record  Sport     SeasonNumber
  1     Football   84
  2     Baseball   76
  3     Basketball 52
  4     Hockey     26
  5     Football   85
  6     Baseball   77
  7     Basketball 53
  8     Hockey     27
```

Because of the way the data is added, I know the order of the Sport column is always going to be the same.

I have another model we'll call Coach that looks like this (only the relevant fields that I am going to ask about are shown for brevity.)

```
Record  Sport      Season  CoachName + otherdata
   1    Football     84    Joe Smith
   2    Football     84    Bob Jones
   3    Football     84    Alex Trebek
   4    Football     84    Computer
   5    Football     84    Computer
   6    Football     84    Computer
   7    Baseball     76    Hank Aaron
   8    Baseball     76    Computer
   9    Football     85    Joe Smith
   10   Football     85    Bob Jones
   11   Football     85    Computer
   12   Football     85    Computer
   13   Football     85    Computer
   14   Football     85    Sam Spade
   ... etc.
```

What I am wanting to do is, for the most recent "combo" of Sport/SeasonNumber [Four sports, only the latest season of each], get a count of the number of CoachNames that are not "Computer".

So first I pull the last 4 records from the Season table

```
    @seasons = Season.last(4)
```

Now I want to iterate through the @seasons array to get the count of human coaches during the latest season for each sport.  If I only had had a single "set" of data (e.g. "Football, 87" , I could do this:

Controller

```
sp=@seasons.sport
sn=@seasons.seasonnumber
humancount=Coach.human(sp,sn)
```

Model

```
scope  :people,  -> {where.not(coachname: "Computer")}

def self.human(sp,sn)
 humans=Coach.people.count.where(["sport = ? and season = ?", sp,sn]) 
end
```

But, what I want to get back is an array that is a count of "football humans", "baseball humans", "basketball humans", and "hockey humans".   How do I pass the results/elements of @seasons to the method and get the array in return?  I'm trying to avoid having to write one query specific for football, one for baseball, one for basketball, and one for hockey.

I *think* the answer lies with using `.map` but I'm just not grokking it.  Or maybe I just need to loop through each "record" in the @seasons array?

Answer (score 0):

```
num_human_football_coaches = Coach.where("name != ?", "Computer").where(sport: "Football").count
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this

```
 Coach.where("name != ?", "Computer").group(:sport).count
```

This would return you what you want.

Comment: Close, but that would return a count for the specific sports across ALL seasons.  I just want to pull a count for one specific season,  I probably wasn't clear about that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just doing it by "brute force".

```
sn=@seasons.seasonnumber
footballhumancount=Coach.human("football",sn)
baseballhumancount=Coach.human("baseball",sn)
basketballhumancount=Coach.human("basketball",sn)
```